# Comboboxes are not showing the next record using the bindingnavigator record selector

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

I am using a Winforms application which has a multitabbed form and it is linked to a MySQL database in Visual Studio Community 2017. The form has bindingsource and bindingnavigator controls. My basic database structure is has follows: -

### Supplies

SupplyID (pk)
SupplyName

### Catalog

CatalogID (pk)
CatalogName

### Years

YearID (pk)
YearNumber

### Colours

ColourID (pk) 
ColourName

### Orders

OrderID (pk)
OrderName
SupplyID_fk (fk)
CatalogID_fk (fk)
YearID_fk (fk)
ColourID_fk (fk)

The Orders table has four comboboxes in it: CboSupplyID_fk, CboCatalogID_fk, CboYearID_fk and CboColourID_fk. My problem is that is when I try to navigator to the next record using the bindingnavigator record selector (except for the CboColourID_fk, which works fine). The vb.net code is shown below: -

The Orders table has four comboboxes in it: CboSupplyID_fk, CboCatalogID_fk, CboYearID_fk and CboColourID_fk. My problem is that is when I try to navigator to the next record using the bindingnavigator record selector (except for the CboColourID_fk, which works fine). The vb.net code is shown below: -

```
Imports MySql
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports MySql.Data

Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

Dim cbCatalog As New MySqlCommandBuilder(daCatalog)
Dim cbYears As New MySqlCommandBuilder(daYears)
Dim cbOrderTypes As New MySqlCommandBuilder(daOrderTypes)
Dim cbOrderColours As New MySqlCommandBuilder(daOrderColours)
Dim dsCatalog As New DataSet
Dim dsYears As New DataSet
Dim dsOrderTypes As New DataSet
Dim dsOrderColours As New DataSet
Dim dsOrders As New DataSet
Dim dsSupplies As New DataSet
Dim dtCatalog As New DataTable
Dim dtYears As New DataTable
Dim dtOrderTypes As New DataTable
Dim dtOrderColours As New DataTable
Dim dtOrders As New DataTable
Dim dtOrderColours As New DataTable
Dim dtSupplies As New DataTable
Dim daCatalog As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim daYears As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim daOrderTypes As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim daOrderColours As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim daOrders As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim daSupplies As New MySqlDataAdapter

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;Port=3306;database=mydatabase;userid=root;password=mypassword;persist security info=True"
    daOrders = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Orders", MysqlConn)
    daOrders.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    Dim dsOrders As New DataSet
    dtOrders = New DataTable("Orders")
    daOrders.Fill(dtOrders)
    dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtOrders)
    Dim cbOrders As New MySqlCommandBuilder(daOrders)
    daSupplies = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Supplies", MysqlConn)
    dtSupplies = New DataTable("Supplies")
    daSupplies.Fill(dtSupplies)
    dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtSupplies)
    cbOrders = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daSupplies)

    daCatalog = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Catalog", MysqlConn)
    dtCatalog = New DataTable("Catalog")
    daCatalog.Fill(dtCatalog)
    dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtCatalog)
    cbOrders = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daCatalog)

    daYears = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Years", MysqlConn)
    dtYears = New DataTable("Years")
    daYears.Fill(dtYears)
    dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtYears)
    cbOrders = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daYears)


    daOrderTypes = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM OrderTypes", MysqlConn)
    dtOrderTypes = New DataTable("OrderTypes")
    daOrderTypes.Fill(dtOrderTypes)
    dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtOrderTypes)
    cbOrders = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daOrderTypes)

    daOrderColours = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM OrderColours", MysqlConn)
    dtOrderColours = New DataTable("OrderColours")
    daOrderColours.Fill(dtOrderColours)
    dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtOrderColours)
    cbOrders = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daOrderColours)

    dtOrders.Columns("OrderID").AutoIncrement = True
    dtSupplies.Columns("SupplyID").AutoIncrement = True

    dtOrders.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtSupplies.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr As DataRow) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtSupplies.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dtSupplies.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtSupplies.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtSupplies.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dsOrders.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("relationSupply", dsOrders.Tables("Supplies").Columns("SupplyID"), dsOrders.Tables("Orders").Columns("SupplyID_fkey")))

    SupplyBindingSource = New BindingSource(dsOrders, "Supplies")

    CboSupplyID_fkey.DisplayMember = "SupplyNumber"
    CboSupplyID_fkey.ValueMember = "SupplyID"
    CboSupplyID_fkey.DataSource = SupplyBindingSource

    OrderBindingSource = New BindingSource(SupplyBindingSource, "relationSupply")

    'bind the Supply's foreign key to the combobox's "SelectedValue" '
    Me.CboSupplyID_fkey.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", Me.OrderBindingSource, "SupplyID_fkey", True))


    dtOrders.Columns("OrderID").AutoIncrement = True
    dtCatalog.Columns("CatalogCodeID").AutoIncrement = True

    dtOrders.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtCatalog.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr As DataRow) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtCatalog.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dtCatalog.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtCatalog.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtCatalog.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dsOrders.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("relationCatalog", dsOrders.Tables("Catalog").Columns("CatalogCodeID"), dsOrders.Tables("Orders").Columns("CatalogCodeID_fk")))

    CatalogBindingSource = New BindingSource(dsOrders, "Catalog")

    CboCatalogCodeID_fk.DisplayMember = "CatalogDescription"
    CboCatalogCodeID_fk.ValueMember = "CatalogCodeID"
    CboCatalogCodeID_fk.DataSource = CatalogBindingSource

    OrderBindingSource = New BindingSource(CatalogBindingSource, "relationCatalog")

    'to clear previous binding and then add new binding '
    CboSupplyID_fkey.DataBindings.Clear()

    'bind the Catalog Guide's foreign key to the combobox's "SelectedValue" '
    Me.CboCatalogCodeID_fk.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", Me.OrderBindingSource, "CatalogCodeID_fk", True))

    dtOrders.Columns("OrderID").AutoIncrement = True
    dtYears.Columns("YearID").AutoIncrement = True

    dtOrders.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtYears.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr As DataRow) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtYears.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dtYears.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtYears.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtYears.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dsOrders.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("relationYears", dsOrders.Tables("Years").Columns("YearID"), dsOrders.Tables("Orders").Columns("YearID_fk")))

    YearBindingSource = New BindingSource(dsOrders, "Years")

    CboYearID_fk.DisplayMember = "YearNumber"
    CboYearID_fk.ValueMember = "YearID"
    CboYearID_fk.DataSource = YearBindingSource

    OrderBindingSource = New BindingSource(YearBindingSource, "relationYears")

    'to clear previous binding and then add new binding '
    CboCatalogCodeID_fk.DataBindings.Clear()

    'bind the Year's foreign key to the combobox's "SelectedValue" '
    Me.CboYearID_fk.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", Me.OrderBindingSource, "YearID_fk", True))



    dtOrders.Columns("OrderID").AutoIncrement = True
    dtOrderTypes.Columns("OrderTypeID").AutoIncrement = True

    dtOrders.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtOrderTypes.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr As DataRow) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtOrderTypes.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dtOrderTypes.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtOrderTypes.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtOrderTypes.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dsOrders.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("relationOrderTypes", dsOrders.Tables("OrderTypes").Columns("OrderTypeID"), dsOrders.Tables("Orders").Columns("OrderTypeID_fk")))

    OrderTypeBindingSource = New BindingSource(dsOrders, "OrderTypes")

    CboOrderTypeID_fk.DisplayMember = "OrderType"
    CboOrderTypeID_fk.ValueMember = "OrderTypeID"
    CboOrderTypeID_fk.DataSource = OrderTypeBindingSource

    OrderBindingSource = New BindingSource(OrderTypeBindingSource, "relationOrderTypes")

    'to clear previous binding and then add new binding '
    CboYearID_fk.DataBindings.Clear()

    'bind the Order Type's foreign key to the combobox's "SelectedValue" '
    Me.CboOrderTypeID_fk.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", Me.OrderBindingSource, "OrderTypeID_fk", True))


    dtOrders.Columns("OrderID").AutoIncrement = True
    dtOrderColours.Columns("ColourID").AutoIncrement = True

    dtOrders.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtOrderColours.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr As DataRow) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtOrderColours.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dtOrderColours.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtOrderColours.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtOrderColours.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dsOrders.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("relationColours", dsOrders.Tables("OrderColours").Columns("ColourID"), dsOrders.Tables("Orders").Columns("ColourID_fk")))

    OrderColourBindingSource = New BindingSource(dsOrders, "OrderColours")

    cboColourID_fk.DisplayMember = "Colour"
    cboColourID_fk.ValueMember = "ColourID"
    cboColourID_fk.DataSource = OrderColourBindingSource

    OrderBindingSource = New BindingSource(OrderColourBindingSource, "relationColours")

    'to clear previous binding and then add new binding '
    CboOrderTypeID_fk.DataBindings.Clear()

    'bind the Catalog Guide's foreign key to the combobox's "SelectedValue" '
    Me.cboColourID_fk.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", Me.OrderBindingSource, "ColourID_fk", True))


    'Bind the DataTable to the UI via a BindingSource. '
    OrderBindingSource.DataSource = dtOrders
    Me.OrderBindingNavigator.BindingSource = Me.OrderBindingSource

    txtOrderID.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.OrderBindingSource, "OrderID")
    txtOrderName.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.OrderBindingSource, "OrderName")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: One thing I see right away is that you are creating 2 of all your data objects; one at the in the declare where you instantiate with `New` and again in the Sub procedure where you instantiate again with `New`

Comment: Hi Mary, Thank you for your comments. Which two objects do you mean?

Comment: `Dim daSupplies As New MySqlDataAdapter` and `daSupplies = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Supplies", MysqlConn)` It seems this happens with all you data objects, not just 2. I meant you are creating 2. You use the `New` keyword twice on the same object. You create one in the declare and then replace it with another new one in the assignment. Each time the constructor of the object is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. I was able to solve my problem by using this vb.net code: -

```
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()

    ' Define the SQL to grab data from table.
    CmdSQLSelectOrders = "SELECT * FROM Orders"

    'Connection String
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
      "server=localhost;Port=3306;database=mydatabase;userid=root;password=mypassword;persist security info=True"
    daOrders.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    ' Try, Catch, Finally
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()

        MysqlCmd.Connection = MysqlConn
        MysqlCmd.CommandText = CmdSQLSelectOrders

        daOrders.SelectCommand = MysqlCmd
        daOrders.Fill(dtOrders)

        daSupplies = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Supplies", MysqlConn)
        dtSupplies = New DataTable("Supplies")
        daSupplies.Fill(dtSupplies)
        dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtSupplies)

        daCatalog = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Catalog", MysqlConn)
        dtCatalog = New DataTable("Catalog")
        daCatalog.Fill(dtCatalog)
        dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtCatalog)

        daYears = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Years", MysqlConn)
        dtYears = New DataTable("Years")
        daYears.Fill(dtYears)
        dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtYears)

        daOrderTypes = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM OrderTypes", MysqlConn)
        dtOrderTypes = New DataTable("OrderTypes")
        daOrderTypes.Fill(dtOrderTypes)
        dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtOrderTypes)

        daOrderColours = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM OrderColours", MysqlConn)
        dtOrderColours = New DataTable("OrderColours")
        daOrderColours.Fill(dtOrderColours)
        dsOrders.Tables.Add(dtOrderColours)

        Me.CboSupplyID_fkey.DisplayMember = "SupplyNumber"
        Me.CboSupplyID_fkey.ValueMember = "SupplyID"
        Me.CboSupplyID_fkey.DataSource = SupplyBindingSource

        Me.CboCatalogID_fk.DisplayMember = "CatalogDescription"
        Me.CboCatalogID_fk.ValueMember = "CatalogID"
        Me.CboCatalogID_fk.DataSource = CatalogBindingSource

        Me.CboYearID_fk.DisplayMember = "Year"
        Me.CboYearID_fk.ValueMember = "YearID"
        Me.CboYearID_fk.DataSource = YearBindingSource


        Me.CboOrderTypeID_fk.DisplayMember = "OrderType"
        Me.CboOrderTypeID_fk.ValueMember = "OrderTypeID"
        Me.CboOrderTypeID_fk.DataSource = OrderTypeBindingSource

        Me.CboColourID_fk.DisplayMember = "Colour"
        Me.CboColourID_fk.ValueMember = "ColourID"
        Me.CboColourID_fk.DataSource = OrderColourBindingSource

        Me.OrderBindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables("dtSupplies")
        Me.OrderBindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables("dtCatalog")
        Me.OrderBindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables("dtYears")
        Me.OrderBindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables("dtOrderTypes")
        Me.OrderBindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables("dtOrderColours")

        Me.OrderBindingNavigator.BindingSource = Me.OrderBindingSource

        Me.CboSupplyID_fk.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", Me.OrderBindingSource, "SupplyID_fk", True)
        Me.CboCatalogID_fk.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", Me.OrderBindingSource, "CatalogID_fk", True)
        Me.CboYearID_fk.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", Me.OrderBindingSource, "YearID_fk", True)
        Me.CboOrderTypeID_fk.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", Me.OrderBindingSource, "OrderTypeID_fk", True)
        Me.CboColourID_fk.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", Me.OrderBindingSource, "ColourID_fk", True)

    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```